# Convert sys.argv to JSON (Regex for matching single letters only, no words)

Tags: python, json, regex, command-line-arguments

I have a problem where I need to convert CLI arguments into a JSON.
A valid JSON representing a two dimensional matrix (i.e. a list of lists) as a single string argument to the CLI tool as demonstrated below.

It will be in one of the following two formats:

> make_df.py '[ ["a","b","c"], [1,2,null], [2,3,4], [5,null,6] ]'

> make_df.py '[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "a": 2, "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 }   ]'

I'm working with the following but it remove the " (double-quotes) around the key/column names.

> input_text = (sys.argv[1:])

I'm currently doing a very bloated version to get around this by using the following

```
input_text = (sys.argv[1:])
input_text = "".join(input_text)

input_string = re.compile("([a-zA-Z])")
input_string = input_string.sub(r'"\1"', input_text)
input_string = input_string.replace('"n""u""l""l"', 'null')
input_string = input_string.strip('\'')

data = json.loads(input_string)  # convert string to json
```

**Questions:**

1. What's a better, more efficient way of doing this.
2. What regex should I be using to select just the single-letter column names from the input text

Comment: From my understanding, single quotes wouldn't change anything in your string, and your double quotes must be preserved. What if you just print `sys.argv[1]`? Does it show your correct json input?

Comment: Both your example inputs seem to work correctly merely by piping them through `json.loads`. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @AdamSmith
When I run the following cmd:
python make_df.py '[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "a": 2, "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]'
This is what the sys.argv does:
Text from args: ['[ { a:1, b:2 }, { a: 2, b:3, c:4 }, { c:6, a:5 } ]']
It changes the "a":1, "b":2 into a:1, b:2
I want to preserve the quotes from CLI

Comment: @AliTou Nope, it doesn't. Infact, I did that earlier but since the input can have spaces between them, the output is changed. 
Note: in **'[ { "a":1** there's a space between [ and {

Comment: What are your OS and your shell?

Comment: @AliTou Windows, Powershell. 
I've also tried it with PyCharm terminal.

Comment: @dragon oh well there's your problem.... On Windows you need to use double quotes for your string delimiters, so you must escape the double quotes in the payload. On *nix the single-quoted argument works fine

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks guys, this was super helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Windows Powershell, the method to preserve quotation marks is a little bit different than *nix systems, and you can use [Here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings) to do it:

```
echo @"
[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "a": 2, "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]
"@
```

The output is exactly the same as the input, preserving your quotation marks. This lets you parse JSON directly in your code, without the need for any regex games.

Hence, you can invoke your Python program like this:

```
python make_df.py @"
[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "a": 2, "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]
"@
```

P.S. If you want to make it more literal, you can replace double quotes around `@`s with single quotes, since they prevent variable expansions.

Comment: Time to give up Windows I guess. Thanks Ali, cheers!

Comment: Windows complicates everything :D Cheers!